# How do I prompt a user for input while still using argc, argv[] in c?

Tags: c, arrays, prompt, cs50, getstring

So i'm completely new to programming and I'm not sure if I'm even asking this correctly. The code does exactly what I want it to as far as output matching input. It's just supposed to spit out the first letter of whatever words you put in.

The problem is I want to prompt the user for input and get a string of words, then enter that into the array I guess? My program now instead has the user put their input on the same line as running the program. I can't figure out how to implement this, nor can I figure out the correct wording to put into google.

```
include <stdio.h>
include <cs50.h>
include <ctype.h>


int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {

        printf("%c", toupper(argv[i][0]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I guess I mainly need to know the syntax, sorry if I've explained this terribly. Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know whether you need me to clarify anthing/

Comment: @rsp `string` is a `typedef` for `char *`, it's part of the `<cs50.h>` header. It is quite universally hated by most C programmers.

Comment: @rsp in CS50 they use `string` as a typedef for `char*`, totally insane, but it "works".

Comment: As for the question itself, are you asking about how to read input from the user using e.g. `scanf` or `fgets` (if you ever heard about those functions)? I suggest you get [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as it will be explained there.

Comment: You are using your program's parameters as input (a.out **one two three**). You have to declare another string array, and fill it with scanf in you main function body.

Comment: @Some programmer dude he just need to read something about C. He did not. Before that any help is pointless

Comment: @PeterJ Dude, I'm in the second week of CS50 course. There isn't supposed to be any prerequisite reading

Comment: You may want to look at [cs50 stack exchange](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Ben Augustine - Dude, you have to read and do self study. With your approach you will have a hard time. This is not an on line C course

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to spit out the uppercase version of the first letter of each string entered by the user, then you don't need an array to store any input; you just read the next character from the input stream, and then decide whether or not to display it.

Use `printf` to write a prompt to the standard output stream (i.e., the console):

```
printf( "Gimme some words: " );
```

Then you'd use `getchar` to read the next input character until we see a newline or EOF has been signaled, meaning you need some kind of a loop.  For this example, a `for` loop is somewhat natural:

```
for ( int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar() )
{
  // process input
}
```

The structure of a `for` loop is:

```
for ( expr1opt ; expr2opt ; expr3opt  )  statement
```

`expr1` is evaluated once before the loop executes.  It's typically used to set the initial loop state.  In this case, we create the `c` variable and assign it the first character read from the input stream.

`expr2` is evaluated before each iteration of the loop body.  The loop body will be executed if this expression evaluates to a non-zero (`true`-ish) value; otherwise, the loop exits.  In this case, we loop as long as EOF has not been signaled on the input stream.  If `expr2` is omitted completely, it's assumed to be `true`.

`expr3` is evaluated *after* each iteration of the loop body.  It's typically used to update the conditions tested in `expr2`.  In this case, we're updating `c` to be the next character read from the input stream.

Note that each of these expressions is *optional*; you can leave amy one or all of them blank if you want.  In fact, it's pretty common to see "infinite" loops in daemons and event-driven GUI interfaces:

```
for ( ;; )
{
  // loop "forever"
}
```

Now, you need to decide whether or not to print out the current character.  If you want to print the first character of each string entered by the user, then you need to decide what "first character in a string" means.  For this example, we'll simply assume that strings are sequences of non-whitespace characters separated by whitespace (blanks, tabs,  etc.).  So basically, you want to print the first *non*-whitespace character following one or more whitespace characters.  This means you need to keep track of whether the last character was whitespace or not.  The easiest way to do it is to declare a second variable to hold the previously-read character:

```
for ( int c = getchar(), last = ' '; c != '\n' && c != EOF; last = c, c = getchar() )
{
  // process input
}
```

In this case, we extend `expr1` to declare and initialize a second variable, `last`.  We initialize `last` to a blank space the first time through so that we have something valid to test against.

We also extend `expr3` to update `last` with the current value of `c` before reading the next character.

So now, we just need to decide whether to print out the current character.  Our rule is going to be, "if the previous character was whitespace **and** the current character is not whitespace, then print the current character".

There's a standard library function, `isspace`, that returns `true` if the argument is a whitespace character:

```
#include <ctype.h> // for isspace function declaration
...
int c = getchar();
if ( isspace( c ) )
{
  // c is a whitespace character
}
```

So we can implement our loop as follows:

```
for ( int c = getchar(), last = ' '; c != EOF; last = c, c = getchar() )
{
  if ( isspace( last ) && !isspace( c ) )
    printf( "%c", toupper( c ) );
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
  printf( "Gimme a bunch of words: " );
  for ( int c = getchar(), last = ' '; c != '\n' && c != EOF; last = c, c = getchar() )
  {
    if ( isspace( last ) && !isspace( c ) )
      putchar( toupper( c ) );
  }
  putchar( '\n' );

  return 0;
}
```

And a sample run:

```
$ ./first
Gimme a bunch of words: this is a test of the emergency broadcast system
TIATOTEBS
```

This version doesn't use `argc` and `argv` at all, and in fact omits them from the definition of `main`.  You can combine the two approaches; use command line arguments if they are there; if not, prompt the user for input:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  if ( argc > 1 )
  {
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
      putchar( toupper( argv[i][0] ) );
    putchar( '\n' );
  }
  else
  {
    printf( "Gimme some words: " );
    for ( int c = getchar(), last = ' '; c != '\n' && c != EOF; last = c, c = getchar() )
    {
      if ( isspace( last ) && !isspace( c ) )
        putchar( toupper( c ) );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So we can do either

```
$ ./first this is a test of the emergency broadcast system
TIATOTEBS
```

or

```
$ ./first
Gimme a bunch of words: This is a test of the emergency broadcast system
TIATOTEBS
```

Answer (score -2):

To get string input from the user, here are the ways that I know:

1. `scanf("%s", str);`
   Ex:

   ```
   char input[50];<br>
   scanf("%49s", input);
   ```
2. `gets(str);` - Deprecated and not recommended.

   Ex:

   ```
   char input[50];<br>
   gets(input);
   ```

Please note that you need to include the necessarily headers for this.

Comment: `gets` is deprecated. And please fix the formatting.

Comment: Except they shouldn't use `gets` as that function is prone to buffer overruns and no longer used

Comment: Prevent buffer overflow with scanf: `scanf("%49s", input);`